# how to integrate a simple captcha with devise at registration in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please tell me how can i integrate simple captcha with devise. How can i use simple_captcha_valid? for captcha authentication in devise registration cont

---

Is there any way i can do custom validation for the authentication of captcha because i cannot make changes in registration controller?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually covered really well in the Devise wiki: [How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise)

Comment: This is for recaptcha, simple captcha do not have such method verify_recaptcha . please if anyone know then tell me

Comment: Why do you want to use captcha instead of recaptcha?

Comment: well because client want captcha

Answer (score 2):

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'user_registrations' }

# app/controllers/user_registrations_controller.rb
class UserRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    if simple_captcha_valid?
      super                   
    else                         
      build_resource         
      resource.errors.add(:base, "Please re-enter the captcha code") if resource.valid?
      render :new                                 
    end               
  end    
end
```

These changes are necessary in addition to the installation instructions described in https://github.com/galetahub/simple-captcha